# Text replacement bash script

Tags: bash, shell, replace, substitution

I want to replace `a'` into `à`, `e'` into `è`, etc. into a file with a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -e "$1" ]
then
  sed  's/a'/\à/g' -i "$1";
  sed  's/e'/\è/g' -i "$1";
  sed  's/i'/\ì/g' -i "$1";
  sed  's/o'/\ò/g' -i "$1";
  sed  's/u'/\ù/g' -i "$1";
else
  echo "File not found!"
fi
```

But I get this error:

`Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

I don't know how to wrote `'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is syntax problem, try your sed command as this:

```
sed -i "s/a'/à/g" "$1"
sed -i "s/e'/è/g" "$1"
sed -i "s/i'/ì/g" "$1"
sed -i "s/o'/ò/g" "$1"
sed -i "s/u'/ù/g" "$1"
```

Problem was that you were using nested single quote (quote inside code).

Comment: But with this code I change `a` into `à` and not `a'` into `à`.

Answer (score 4):

Exit the single quotes, then put an escaped quote, then start another single quoted string:

```
sed  's/a'\''/\à/g' -i "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ gsub(/e'\''/,"è"); print}' "$1"
```

Comment: The same fix would apply to `sed`. There's no reason to replace a perfectly good `sed` command with `awk` here.

Comment: But I have not replaced anyone's SED command. I thought that there is independence to post your answer whichever way the requester gets benefited. If you like, you can delete my answer.I dont have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution available in `bash` is `$'...'` quoting, which does allow escaped single quotes:

```
sed  $'s/a\'/\à/g' -i "$1";
```